# how to convert a println output to a dataframe in Scala

Tags: python, scala, apache-spark, printing, databricks

I have this code which generates a list by means of a `for`, I look for the output of the `println` to pass it to a dataframe to be able to manipulate the resulting damage, in Scala.

```
for (l <- ListArchive){  
     val LastModified: (String, String) =(l,getLastModifiedLCO(l))
     println(LastModified)
  }
```

Output `println (LCO_2014-12-09_3.XML.gz,Tue Dec 09 07:48:30 UTC 2014)`
(LCO_2014-12-09_1.XML.gz,Tue Dec 09 07:48:30 UTC 2014)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rewrite it to generate a list/sequence, and then turn into a DataFrame. Something like this:

```scala
import spark.implicits._
val df = ListArchive.map(l => (l, getLastModifiedLCO(l)))
  .toDF("col1Name", "col2Name")
```

If the list is very big, then you can try to turn it into an RDD via `parallelize`, and then apply similar `map` to it, but it will run in the distributed manner.

Comment: correct it worked for me